# pyspark to split array and get key values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I Have dataframe containing array of key value pairs string, i want to get only keys from the key value
Number of key value pairs is dynamic for each row and naming conventions are different.

```
Sample Input
------+-----+-----+-----+---------------------
|ID    |data| value                          |
+------+-----+-----+--------+-----------------
|e1    |D1  |["K1":"V1","K2":"V2","K3":"V3"] |
|e2    |D2  |["K1":"V1","K3":"V3"]           |
|e3    |D1  |["K1":"V1","K2":"V2"]           |
|e4    |D3  |["K2":"V2","K1":"V1","K3":"V3"] |
+------+-----+-----+--------+-----------------


Expected Result:

------+-----+-----+------
|ID    |data| value     |
+------+-----+-----+----|
|e1    |D1  |[K1|K2|K3] |
|e2    |D2  |[K1|K3]    |
|e3    |D1  |[K1|K2]    |
|e4    |D3  |[K2|K1|K3] |
+------+-----+-----+-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function.

For each element of the array, substring the key using [`substring_index`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#substring_index) and trim leading and trailing quotes using [`trim`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#trim) function.

```
df.show(truncate=False)
#+---+----+------------------------------------+
#|ID |data|value                               |
#+---+----+------------------------------------+
#|e1 |D1  |["K1":"V1", "K2": "V2", "K3": "V3"] |
#|e2 |D2  |["K1": "V1", "K3": "V3"]            |
#|e3 |D1  |["K1": "V1", "K2": "V2"]            |
#|e4 |D3  |["K2": "V2", "K1": "V1", "K3": "V3"]|
#+---+----+------------------------------------+    

new_value = """ transform(value, x -> trim(BOTH '"' FROM substring_index(x, ':', 1))) """
df.withColumn("value", expr(new_value)).show()

#+---+----+------------+
#|ID |data|value       |
#+---+----+------------+
#|e1 |D1  |[K1, K2, K3]|
#|e2 |D2  |[K1, K3]    |
#|e3 |D1  |[K1, K2]    |
#|e4 |D3  |[K2, K1, K3]|
#+---+----+------------+
```

If you want the result as a string delimited by `|`, you can use [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join) like this:

```
df.withColumn("value", array_join(expr(new_value), "|")).show()
#+---+----+--------+
#|ID |data|value   |
#+---+----+--------+
#|e1 |D1  |K1|K2|K3|
#|e2 |D2  |K1|K3   |
#|e3 |D1  |K1|K2   |
#|e4 |D3  |K2|K1|K3|
#+---+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the value into array which contains key and value.

```
df.withColumn("keys", expr('transform(value, keyValue -> trim(split(keyValue, ":")[0]))')).drop("value")
```

Comment: Right, there is some limitation on arraytype column iterable. So you can change into: df.withColumn("keys", expr('transform(value, keyValue -> trim(split(keyValue, ":")[0]))')).drop("value").